# Are there a way to avoid the blink at the beggining and the white space delay in the blazor virtualize component?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

Using the blazor virtualize component, I noticed a blink in the first row (or item loaded) into the virtualize. Also I noticed, using the `placeholder`, when I scroll down, the "placeholder" remains with a white space. Are there a way to avoid this blink at the beginning and the white space delay?

For the example, I'm using this project: https://github.com/Amaurys/BlazorVirtualizeExample

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this issue on github for the white spaces: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28056

Comment: Hi @Amaurys Sánchez, so it seems by design and it contains possibility to be fixed in next spring planning?